# Spring AccessDeniedException: Access is denied but login was successful (and I get redirected to home)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

I implemented an `LDAP-Authentication` that works out fine for authentication (so far). I can try to enter false credentials and I am not redirected and the login is not accepted. When I enter true credentials I get logged in & redirected, but also I get the following exception:

```
2018-12-27 17:43:49.807 DEBUG 9920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/home'; against '/logout'
2018-12-27 17:43:49.808 DEBUG 9920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /home at position 9 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2018-12-27 17:43:49.808 DEBUG 9920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /home at position 10 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2018-12-27 17:43:49.809 DEBUG 9920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
2018-12-27 17:43:49.809 DEBUG 9920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /home at position 11 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2018-12-27 17:43:49.811 DEBUG 9920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /home at position 12 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2018-12-27 17:43:49.813 DEBUG 9920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6e15f2c6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2018-12-27 17:43:49.816 DEBUG 9920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /home at position 13 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2018-12-27 17:43:49.816 DEBUG 9920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Requested session ID C5FAE3BFE167F2A00FAC1DF53B2A7B23 is invalid.
2018-12-27 17:43:49.818 DEBUG 9920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /home at position 14 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2018-12-27 17:43:49.818 DEBUG 9920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /home at position 15 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2018-12-27 17:43:49.820 DEBUG 9920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /home; Attributes: [fullyAuthenticated]
2018-12-27 17:43:49.820 DEBUG 9920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6e15f2c6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2018-12-27 17:43:49.827 DEBUG 9920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@f21cb05, returned: -1
2018-12-27 17:43:49.834 DEBUG 9920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
        at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:52) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:206) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
```

**My class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${ad.domain}")
    private String AD_DOMAIN;

    @Value("${ad.url}")
    private String AD_URL;

    @Autowired
    UserRoleComponent userRoleComponent;

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        this.logger.info("Verify logging level");
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                        System.out.println("Autentication Success handler invoked");
                        userRoleComponent.testIt();
                        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/");
                    }
                })
            .and()
                .httpBasic()
            .and()
                .logout()//.logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
        http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(AD_DOMAIN,
                AD_URL);
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

Why is that? I cannot make out why I get this exception (Which says Access denied, so it should not pass me on) and still I am logged in and can also access the `SecurityContext` which gives me right results when it comes to the username etc. - What is not executed is the `successHandler`.

Edit: I am connected via VPN. Could that cause the error?

Comment: can you post all the information about this user on your ldap config?

Comment: @slimane I dont think so, since this is a corporate environment, yet, what would you be looking for?

Comment: just curious about what roles does he have?

Comment: If you mean the results of `getAuthorities()` it is mostly e-mail groups and some "internal groups" so to say, nothing special. I do not have any administrator-privileges, if you wanted to know that one

Comment: The log is clear: You are not logged in. Are you sure, that the request contains the session cookie?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?